# How do I set the orientation for an application in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a 1366 x 768p display, and I'm making an application on it using Kivy. However, I'm using
the display in a vertical orientation. How do I make it so that my application displays In vertical orientation?

```
kivy.require('1.8.0')
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.app import App

class SimpleKivy(App):
  def build(self):
    return Label(text = "TEST")

if __name__ = "__main__":
  SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: Duplicate question, answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639430/forcing-a-kivy-widgets-orientation-to-be-landscape-portrait

Answer (score 0):

Orientation can be set in buildozer.spec

```
# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait
```

also for a better representation on desktop you can use kivy.Config from 
[Kivy docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html?highlight=config#module-kivy.config)

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'top', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 1366)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 768)
```

Also you should use the latest Kivy Version 1.11.1 unless you do this for a specific reason.